# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) on projec

Tags: java, maven, selenium, jenkins, java-11

i am testing Automation engineer, I have configured Jenkins and maven project for the automate the scripts, some days ago my all scripts were working good in Jenkins and locally, but Now when I run build in Jenkins and locally system through exception, locally when I tries to update my maven project and run scripts through command "maven test" its working fine and all scripts running when i tries to run command "maven clean " and then run command run as "maven test" then system generates me an error , when i try to run same porm.xml file from jenkins without command "clean test" its working fine but with command  always facing same kind of exception 
.
 "ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project EventBuizz: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /E:/Automation/eclipse-workspace/EventBuizz/src/test/java/EventBuizz/EventBuizz/EventCenterDashBoard.java:[21,34] package org.apache.tools.ant.types does not exist
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:"

I have looked through the other posts for this and made some changes to my .pom file as suggested but I am still stuck with the same error. Unsure what other useful info to provide so please let me know what other info would be useful to troubleshoot this. Below is my .pom file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    >
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>EventBuizz</groupId>
    <artifactId>EventBuizz</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>


    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
         </properties>
    <dependencies>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.shared</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-tree</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Selenium -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- TestNG -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.14.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--JUnit -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--Maven Plugin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <type>maven-plugin</type>



        </dependency>

        <!--Extent Report -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.relevantcodes</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>2.41.2</version>
        </dependency>

<dependency>
  <!-- jsoup HTML parser library @ https://jsoup.org/-->
  <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
  <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
  <version>1.12.1</version>
</dependency>

    </dependencies>



    <build>
        <plugins>

            <!--Maven Plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!--Maven surfire plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8</version>
                <configuration>
                    <printSummary>true</printSummary>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>





</project>
```

i want to run my test scripts in jenkins with command "clean test".

Answer (score 0):

`testCompile` phase compiles the application test sources. If this phase fails, then the `test` Phase will fail. 
Check the error you are getting - 
`Compilation failure [ERROR] /E:/Automation/eclipse-workspace/EventBuizz/src/test/java/EventBuizz/EventBuizz/EventCenterDashBoard.java:[21,34] package org.apache.tools.ant.types does not exist`
I would start debugging it by checking this class. It seems that the library - `org.apache.tools.ant.types` is missing in your project.

Comment: Thanks for your response: i have Import the org.apache.tools.ant.types but still facinfg the same issue

Comment: when i clean my project and and after that run my script then this Error message is displayed  Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project EventBuizz: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] /E:/Automation/eclipse-workspace/EventBuizz/src/test/java/EventBuizz/EventBuizz/RegSite_generalRegSiteSettings.java:[4,1] package org.apache.tools.ant.types does not exist

Comment: The error now is on a different class - generalRegSiteSettings.java The numbers [1,4]] next to it are a line numbers (to where the compilation error occurs). It seems that the error is on the beginning, so it most likely related to the library import. I would recommend you to check this class to see for the error and to any other class that a similar error occurs.

Comment: even i had put org.apache.tools.ant.types in all my classes  but the system shows me the same error

Comment: i had put the import org.apache.tools.ant.types.*; but same error is displayed